# Program received signal SIGKILL exception comes up when I quit in the multitasking bar (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sigkill

When I double tap the home button and quit out of my app from the multitasking bar and open the app again, Xcode reads: "Thread 1: program received signal: SIGKILL" and freezes my iPod. The app has 1500+ lines so I can't really put any code up, sorry. What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

*Your 1500+ lines of code is really innocent of this crash.*

It happens when you run the app from *Xcode*, and terminate it from the *iPod*, without stopping the execution from *Xcode*. Closing the app from multitasking bar doesn't stop its execution in Xcode(*but, I always expect it to do*). So, when you open it again, the Xcode throws that *SIGKILL* exception. And, it doesn't do any harm to your app. No need to worry about it.

*And, ofcourse, I don't know any technical explanation for this behavior. I am not that genious ;-)*

Answer (score 2):

That's normal, your app is receiving a signal that it has to terminate.

Just make sure that when it does, you handle it properly in one of the UIApplication delegate methods, so that no information is lost, and such.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and the reason was lost connection between XCode and device.