# When I kill an app it crashes, what to do?

Tags: xcode, crash, sigkill

Whenever I load my application to my iPhone it works just fine, but when I kill it(double tap the home button and kill it) and launch it again it freezes and crashes. I am quite new to programming so what should I do? Do I have to do something in the appdelegate file or what?

Comment: Your original app obviously leaves something behind that it should have cleaned up. Without at least SOME understanding of what your app actually does, it's hard to advice on what you should do.

Comment: Is it possible ? I think answer is NO. Please re identify your question.

Comment: well I do have some understanding of what I am doing...

Comment: @sagarcool89   it is possible when the iPhone is under debug mode, when he is debugging on the real iPhone, it occurs

Comment: if you app crash under debug mode after you manually killed it , it's fine,you don't have to worry about it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Program recieved signal SIGKILL exception comes up when I quit in the multitasking bar (iPhone)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566799/program-recieved-signal-sigkill-exception-comes-up-when-i-quit-in-the-multitaski)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you manually killed your APP on your iphone while you are debugging using xcode ,

your APP will receive a signal(maybe SIGKILL , not sure) ,

as you are in debug mode , xcode can show you that, it's normal & don't have to do anything

if your APP is running in normal mode, then you killed it , your APP will just exit & relaunch again next you run it