# App Crash at the time close app using home button?

Tags: ios

Program recieved signal SIGKILL exception comes up when I quit in the multitasking bar.
because of that **applicationWillTerminate(app delegate Method)** doesn't called. so I have lost some unsaved data.

Comment: Unclear question...please edit.  There is nothing you can do to react to getting terminated in the background.  So instead, you should react to going into the background.

Comment: @VinodJadhav please check your plist background running is must yes..

Comment: in my plist UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend is YES

Comment: @VinodJadhav ... have you checked all UIApplication environment methods ... please debug all the code so that you can get to know the problem which you are facing for your app.(cause only you know that what kind of code is written to your project)

Comment: I have received SIGKILL exception whenever I remove app.

Comment: R u debugging in real device?

Comment: yes I have debugging on real device as well as simulator.

Comment: Dear @VinodJadhav. Whenever u r debugging and when u do this type operation, app will crash. it not harmful to ur app for more information you can check http://stackoverflow.com/a/6567345/2522457.

Comment: I have already checked that link but because of that my application will terminate method doesn't called in this method my unsaved data save logic is here. because of that my changed data or unsaved data not saving.